# calling ImagePipeline from getview got an exception Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager postImagesViewPager;
        ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(CommonUtilities.SERVER_IMAGE_URL +"user_background_" +userid+ ".jpeg?w=600&h=300"); 
        ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri).build();
        DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(request,getActivity());

    DataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSubscriber =  new BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>() {

        @Override
        protected void onFailureImpl(DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onNewResultImpl( DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!arg0.isFinished()) {
              System.out.println("Not yet finished - this is just another progressive scan.");
            }  

            CloseableReference<CloseableImage> imageReference = arg0.getResult();
            if (imageReference != null) {
              try {
                  CloseableBitmap image = (CloseableBitmap)imageReference.get();
                  Bitmap bitmap = image.getUnderlyingBitmap();
                  viewpagerDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
                  postImagesViewPager.setBackground(viewpagerDrawable);

              } catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally {
                imageReference.close();
              }
            }
        }
    };
    Executor ex = new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            command.run();
        }
    };
    Runnable runr = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Runnig to get image from facebook.......");
        }
    };
    dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, ex);
    ex.execute(runr);

    return _rootView;
}
```

Comment: Is that your `getView()` method??

Comment: in onCreateView method

Comment: The code you posted, Is that the `getView()` method?

Comment: no in fragment onCreateView() method

Comment: If the exception is in `getView()` method, its better to post that code. don't you think?

Comment: first time i didn't get these exception but when i load image second time by invalidation by removing

 Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getSmallImageDiskStorageCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(uri1.toString()));